# How change value of "Press Fn to" in Keyboard preferences programmatically?

Tags: keyboard, preferences, swift

I need to change value of "Press Fn to" programmatically to "Do Nothing". I can't find a direct way to switch this. I believe that is possible do this with AppleScript, but will need to trigger system preferences application in background.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fn on its own already 'does nothing'. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to get the value of “press Fn to” and then change it programmatically. But I can't find any plist that contains that value.